# ROS Answers SE migration: IP Camera Node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone written a node to read an mjpeg and/or mpeg4 stream off a an IP camera such as the D-Link [DCS-932](http://mydlink.dlink.com/products/DCS-932L)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36767/ip-camera-node/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have one [here](http://clearpath-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clearpath_common/clearpath_sensors/) which works for Axis cameras (note: we will be moving our stuff to GitHub soon and reorganizing the package structure).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-02-21**:
It's now here: https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/axis_camera

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2017-02-16**:
do they work with other cameras¿ or only with Axis ones?